# Golang Base64 to Hex conversion

Tags: go, base64, hex

Why does Golang base64 to Hex produce a different encoding value than the online converter?

Original String:

> ARVIN

Base64 encoded:

> QVJWSU4=

Golang (base64 to hex):

> 51564a575355343d

Online ([base64 to hex](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex)):

> 415256494e

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    base64 := "QVJWSU4="
    hx := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(base64))
    fmt.Println("Original String: ARVIN")
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(base64 + " ==> " + hx)
}
```

Comment: Already found the solution... It does not have to convert the base64 to hex. the CORRECT WAY is STRING => HEX. What i am doing WRONG is STRING => BASE64 => HEX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the un-encoded value directly to hex:

```
h := hex.EncodeToString([]byte("ARVIN"))
fmt.Println(h) // prints 415256494e
```

Given the program starts with the base64 encoding, the program must decode the base64 string to bytes and then encode the bytes to a hex string. This is what the online tool does.

The code in the question encodes the base64 string to a hex string. It's missing the decode step.

Here's how to re-encode base64 to hex in Go:

```
p, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("QVJWSU4=")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
h := hex.EncodeToString(p)
fmt.Println(h) // prints 415256494e
```

[Run it in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-j7LJcgJW1D).